# How to deal with multiple info and debug flags

Tags: python, if-statement, flags

I'm writing a python program for some time and I have a lot of code. Mainly, I use printing statements and writing into files for debugging purposes.

Because I do not want all the time to do debug I made some flags on top of the file "print_info = False" or "print_to_file = False ". The problem here is that my code looks like that

```py
if print_to_file:
   write_file("blah")
if print_info :
   print("blah")

...
...

if print_to_file:
   write_file("blah blah")
if print_info :
   print("blah blah blah")
```

I felt that the code looks a little bit unprofessional and I made some methods but stil I do not like it:

```py
def print_useful_info_to_file(info):
    if print_to_file:
       write_file(info)

def print_debug_method(info):
     if print_to_file:
        write_file(info)
     if print_info :
        print(info)
```

Is there any good practice how to write this in a beautiful manner?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into python's `logging` module? This is the most common way to manage this type of system in python.

Comment: Use built-in library `logging`. There are lots of documentations and recipes you can find.

Comment: I already use the logging module the problem is with console statements. And I really need those ones.

Comment: You can configure `logging` to write to console or file, or both. You do not seem to use `logging` in your shown code.